# How to make multiple line breaks in markdown to create white space, without typing multiple <br /> instances

Tags: html, markdown

Introductory HTML student, I'm trying to learn how to make multiple line breaks without having to type multiple `<br />` when using a WYSIWYG editor.

The solutions I've read so far suggest adding two spaces to the end of a line prior to moving to to the next line and this will create a space between paragraphs.
However when I attempt to add two spaces at the beginning of an empty line and press enter to move to the next, my output preview does not show that I'm creating additional blank lines.

The goal is to be able to add up to 4 blank lines between some paragraphs in the output content to help meet a formatting goal. My current best working solution is to type 4 `<br />` in a row like this:

```
<!-- content here then four spaces to create white space before next content -->
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<!-- next content -->
```

Is there another solution when writing in markdown to get a similar result? 
The goal is to be able to easily create multiple (at least 4) line breaks when desired between paragraphs.  Easily here means without having to type out `<br />` or `<br>` every time I want to do this.

Any help is appreciated, and -if applicable-:

- deeper understandings of how this process works,
- recommendations on your fav literature, blogs, or documentation regarding this topic, and
- any advice & anecdotes from a more experienced viewpoint about how you think about this kind of issue now, as opposed to how I am thinking about it in a more novice state.

Answer (score 1):

depending on the WYSIWYG editor if you can access the CSS you could play with:

br { display:block; margin-top:10px; line-height:22px; }

increase the 10px and the 22px line-height to your convenience...
other than that I don't know... don't really see the downside of 

 (yes they can be on the same line)
it's just copy&paste after all?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion however for this situation I either cannot, or do not have the skill to edit the CSS of the editor right now.   Copy paste <br /> multiple times on a single line is a good idea.  I'd still like to know if there is a better method or one that doesn't have me type <br /> to achieve the goal.  Like how adding two blank spaces to the end of a line starts a new line, I'd like to start multiple new lines, just have them be blank.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can change HTML code in this WYSIWYG editor (you did not specified which one it is), then you can also use style="" (CSS). Just make margin on paragraphs. You can use pixels (px) value, but if you wanna have value based on current font size then "em" will be better solution.

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat corporis aliquid adipisci alias vel. Odit consectetur saepe velit vel distinctio enim ipsam aperiam eaque, reiciendis itaque officiis ad fuga dolorem!</p>

<p style="margin-top: 3em">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat corporis aliquid adipisci alias vel. Odit consectetur saepe velit vel distinctio enim ipsam aperiam eaque, reiciendis itaque officiis ad fuga dolorem!</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat corporis aliquid adipisci alias vel. Odit consectetur saepe velit vel distinctio enim ipsam aperiam eaque, reiciendis itaque officiis ad fuga dolorem!</p>
```

Comment: Similar to the suggestion above, I appreciate this solution.  However I'm currently either not able to or do not have the skill to edit the CSS of the editor right now.  I do appreciate this idea, and I am interested in a different solution if anyone knows of one.

Comment: This is not editing CSS of editor or site itself, is CSS of content. Copy paste solution not different than <br>...

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'll explore this some as I may not have sufficient enough understanding about coding HTML/CSS to appreciate your original solution answer.  Thank you again for your help. 

(ie. it's more likely you gave the best solution for my question, and I not only don't really understand the answer, I probably don't really understand the question I'm asking)